# Remove tolerance in PostGIS requests

Tags: sql, php, request, tolerance

I just read the problems similar to mine on this forum, but no solution helped me.

To put it simply, I use ST_Touches in an algo in PHP that allows me to test if two points touch.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_node1, t_node2 
WHERE st_touches (t_node1.geom, t_node2.geom)
```

The problem is that there is a tolerance and therefore my results are not accurate.

Is there a way to remove this tolerance?

Comment: Show us a concrete example with two geometries which do not touch even PostGIS claims that they do.

Comment: Most folks have issues with objects which *should* touch, but don't quite due to floating-point representation issues. I've never heard of such a tolerance in PostGIS, though Esri geometry does.